# Javascript on a new page load to move an anchor below a top fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, onload

I'm just learning javascript (literally) and I've got a bit of JS (below) that moves page anchors 90 pixels down from the top of the page, to prevent the contents of the anchor from being overlapped by a fixed top element. When clicking links to anchors on the same page, it works beautifully.

The problem I'm having is when I click a link that points to an anchor on a different page. When the new page loads, the anchor is loaded at the top of the page and is partially hidden underneath the fixed top element.

I suspect I need some sort of onLoad event on every page that checks for anchor hashes, but I'm too new to this to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Statistical info: I'm doing this for my company's web help. We have about 280+ help pages and 2,500 or so anchors. I'm hoping that adding some JS to an include or header will solve my issue.

Note: The script I'm using I found as an answer to a different stackoverflow question and is lightly modified.

```
$(function(){
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var $target = (this.hash);
      $target = target.length && target || ('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if ($target.length) {
        var targetOffset = target.offset().top - 90;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this with some CSS (I added a class to all my anchors):

```
a.target
{
    position: relative;
    border-top: 90px solid transparent;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    margin: -100px 0 0;
}

a.target:before
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -90px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work pretty well. Tested in Firefox and Chrome.

```
$(function(){
  if(location.hash !== "") {
    window.scrollTo(0,window.pageYOffset-90);
  }
});
```

Comment: This works for a brief second. But, after loading the page at the offset the page resets to putting the target anchor at the top of the page (so it is hidden by the top fixed element).

I even set it to offset to the bottom of the page, and I can briefly see the content at the bottom of the page before everything gets moved.

Comment: I did a step through with Firebug. I can see that window.scrollTo is working and putting the content where I want it, but after the close } is processed for the if statement, the content resets to where it was before the window.scrollTo line. Maybe I'm not implementing it correctly - have you got any more suggestions?

Comment: You may need to put the window.scrollTo in a setTimeout function and allow there to be a small delay (I'm sure something less than 500ms would work). Probably not the best solution, but its the best I can think of off the top of my head at the moment. If I get a chance to experiment more, I'll see if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly; you want this move to happen on page load and not just when a link is clicked. If that's the case, you will want to use the each() function instead of click(). Just replace .click with .each and it will happen once the page loads. Also, wrap your href match in double quotes to be safe.

```
  $('a[href*="#"]').each(function() {...
```